# Why am I observing spin-orbit coupling in only one direction (spin up or spin down) in SIESTA (DFT)?

Tags: siesta

Can someone provide guidance on how to include Spin-orbit Coupling (SoC) for the band structure calcualtion using SIESTA?

I have used the #Flag #Spin spin-orbit, but I only obtained spin dependence in one direction. Are there any other flags needed to obtain results for both up and down spins, or any alternative approaches to achieve this?

Comment: +1 Welcome to our forum!

Comment: I believe this is what you are looking for https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/8457/how-to-obtain-spin-projected-band-structure-for-system-with-spin-orbit-coupling

Comment: It is hard to know what you mean? Spin-orbit means you'll get a vector of spin, there is no "spin-up vs down", since the angles can vary in between. If you want spin-up/down to be separate spin-channels, then you would use a polarized calculation.

Comment: using Spin-orbit explicitly means you won't have spin up/down separated in the calculations since they are interlinked. So I think you misinterpret what it really means?